# Type constraint for equality requires explicit cast

Tags: scala

I am using a type constraint to say that types `A` and `B` must be the same. Below, I am permitted to implicitly cast from `A` to `B`, but need an explicit cast to go from `B` to `A`. What is the correct way to do this?

```
class Pair[A, B](var first: A, var second: B) {
  def swap()(implicit ev: A =:= B) {
    val tmp = second
    second = first
    first = tmp //won't compile without appending .asInstanceOf[A]
  }

  /*
  ...other methods like replaceFirst, replaceSecond that 
     don't require types A, B to be the same
  */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`A =:= B` witness that `A` type is equal to type `B`. Then you must tell compiler that `B` type is equal `A` type. Do this with **`B =:= A`** :)

See below introduced new **`ev2`** parameter:

```
class Pair[A, B](var first: A, var second: B) {
  def swap()(implicit ev:  =:=[A,B], ev2:  =:= [B,A])  {
    val tmp = second
    second = first
    first = tmp
}
```

BTW: Some guys advice: *"use only one type parameter"*. If you follow this way you won't be able to define other methods/functions in you `Pair` class that don't need such constraint.